# How to upload a file from multiple forms that saves it under a certain name?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a table that has 5 upload forms.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
  Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

Here is my `upload.php` file:

$destination_path = $_REQUEST["destination"] . "upload/"; 
    $target_path = "" . $destination_path;
    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

```
echo "User=" .          $_ENV[USER] . "<br />";
echo "Source=" .        $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'] . "<br />"; 
echo "Destination=" .   $destination_path . "<br />"; 
echo "Target path=" .   $target_path . "<br />"; 
echo "Size=" .          $_FILES['uploadedfile']['size'] . "<br />"; 
//echo "Tmp name=" .    $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'] . "<br />"; 

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
  echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
" has been uploaded";
} else {
  echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

So the problem is twofold:

1. How could I name the file `msg1.txt`, `msg2.txt`, etc.. in the
   target destination no matter what the name of the users text file?
2. How can I filter through five different forms using one
   `upload.php`?

Comment: you have MANY problems with this code. 1) you don't check if the upload was successful. 2) you're using an undefined `$_REQUEST['destination']` to build your `$target_path` 3) if you don't want the user-provided filename, then why are you using it to build the rest of `$target_path`? The destination filename is **ENTIRELY** under your control, so you can name it however you want. the original client-side filename is purely informational.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Marc B already wrote: The destination filename is all up to you as you write the server-side code. But: Your code has serious flaws and you should try improve it (this is even more important if its a public site).

To answer your second question: You could add another hidden input holding the "destination" the form is meant for. Like:
`<input type="hidden" name="dest_name" value="msg1">` 
and then put a switch-statement for $_POST['dest_name'] in your upload.php